# WPF DataGrid - scroll to selected cell horizontally (programatically)

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

is there a posibility to scroll horizontally to a selected cell in datagrid?
With `dataGrid.ScrollIntoView(item)` it works great vertically, but not horizontally.

The `ItemsSource` is a `List<object>` and the item mentioned above is such an `object`. So its clear that there is no info off the selected cell.

Any clues how to achieve this programatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is no elaborated answer, yet

```
dataGrid.ScrollIntoView(row, col)
```

should already do what you want